# Get the remaining list of element after removing a particular element list out of a java list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Imagine I have a list of elements.

`List<Session> sessions;`

Imagine this is populated with some elements.

And I have another list which is a sub list of the above list.

```
List<Session> successSessions;
```

As name suggests, the latter is the set of success sessions out of the first list. Therefore the remaining list is the list of `failedSessions`.

What is an effective way to get `failedSessions` populated using the whole list of sessions and `successSessions`?

Thank You in advance.!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `removeAll` as:

```
List<Session> failedSessions = new ArrayList<>(sessions); // initialise with 'sessions'
failedSessions.removeAll(successSessions);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a Copy of `Session` like this

```
List<Session> allSession = new ArrayList<>(sessions);
```

Remove all `successSessions` from `allSession` using `removeAll` like this

```
allSession.removeAll(successSessions);
```

remaining sessions are `failedSessions`